# Unexpected non_personalized_ads in user snapshot stream - Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, ads, firebase-analytics

I have an app developed in Flutter with Firebase Analytics configured.
I was looking at Stream View inside Firebase Analytics and I noticed this in one of the users stream

[image: user stream view]

The case is that I don't have *any* ads inside my app. Should I be worried (eg. that some package I use is doing it) or is there some explanation why non_personalized_ads tag appeared in the stream?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From analytics docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection?platform=android#re-enable_peronalized_advertising_features

> When ad personalization signals have been disabled for a user via one
>   of the mechanisms defined above, subsequent event bundles logged from
>   that user's device will contain a user property named
>   **"non_personalized_ads" with a value of 1 to indicate that events in that bundle are not available for personalized advertising**.

and

> Note: **Google may in certain circumstances disable personalized advertising for analytics data collected from an end user, even when you have not done so**, where Google has information that the respective
>   end user is not eligible for personalized advertising (for example,
>   the end user on an Android device is under the applicable age per our
>   advertising policies).